# How to access a shared/network folder using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, windows, html, shared-directory

I have a requirement to develop a tool to backup certain folders and files present in a shared drive (Windows 7) using Client-Side technologies (HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript) only. Below is the JavaScript function to copy the file.

```
function copyFile() {
    var myObject, f;
    myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    f = myObject.GetFile("@\\Network_Name\Home$\User_Folder\Downloads\Folder_Name\Test.pdf");
    if(!f)
    {
        return alert("File Not Found");
    }
    f.copy("@\\Network_Name\Home$\User_Folder\Downloads\Backup_Folder");
}
```

Since I'm using `ActiveXObject`, the above code will work only in IE. But I'm getting the below error in the line `@\\Network_Name\Home$\User_Folder\Downloads\Folder_Name\Test.pdf`. Please help me to properly access the network folder using JavaScript.

[image: Snapshot of Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verbatim identifier (`@`) is for C# not JavaScript, you need to escape your slashes:

```
.GetFile("\\\\Network_Name\\Home$\\User_Folder\\Downloads\\Folder_Name\\Test.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Ajax request method type "GET" for this purpose.

Comment: Hi [Vatsal](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6240108/vatsal-pathak), can you please provide me a code sample to access network drive using `$.get()` method.

Comment: Ajax communicates with a web server not a network file system.

Comment: $.get({
  url:@\\Network_Name\Home$\User_Folder\Downloads\Folder_Name\Test.pdf ,
  data: DataToBeInserted,//optional
  success: function({ 
    }),
  dataType: text
});